# Delphi Even Odd Problems

Tags: delphi

Having a problem whenever i want when typing in 2 4 6 8 10 etc i want to have the answer to come out as Even but cant seem to to find the solutioin

```
 if (Edit1.Text = '2' )  then
    Edit2.Text := 'Even'
  else
  Edit2.Text := 'Odd'
```

Tryed to divide 2 but it always fails.

Comment: Convert string to number with `StrToInt`function, then apply `Odd`function. And don't forget to read a book about Delphi/Pascal language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to first convert the text in the textbox to a numeric type like `Integer`, and then compare that value by modulus of 2 (the remainder of integer division):

```
var
  value: Integer;
begin
...
  value := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  if ((value mod 2) = 0) then
    Edit2.Text := 'Even'
  else
    Edit2.Text := 'Odd';
...
end;
```

There is nice and short explanation on `mod` operator here:

- [FreePascal Wiki on Mod](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Mod):

> `mod` (modulus) divides two numbers and returns only the remainder that
>   is a whole number. For instance, the expression `a:= 13 mod 4;` would
>   evaluate to `1` (`a=1`), while `b := 12 mod 4;` would evaluate to `0` (`b=0`).

Comment: Also take a look at David's answer below, its shorter version of the same operation. I would also recommend you to find one of Marco Cantu's books on Delphi (For example `Essential Pascal` and `Essential Delphi` at http://www.marcocantu.com/edelphi/default.htm).

Comment: The documentation for mod is here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Arithmetic_Operators

Answer (score 11):

Convert the text to an integer and use the [`Odd`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Odd) function:

```
if Odd(StrToInt(Text)) then
  // the value is odd
```